# Is it possible with Beautiful soup to get text in Search and click on Submit

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

URL = "https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Default.jsp"

I want to scrape data for list of Cusip from this website using python.

To start with need help what is the best way to look for CUSIP in search tab apart from Selenium.

Comment: That depends. If the button is already exposed in the code as a component then you can deftly do it. However, it renders after some action it might be trickier.

Comment: so can you provide a few examples of text you want to insert into search?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire 61760QFD1

Comment: I want to scrape maturity date and coupon rate for list of cusips. Example : 61760QFD1